# Are there any geology symbol libraries for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, geology

Are there any **structural-geology symbols** libraries (and geology in general) for QGIS?

Comment: I am currently working through the USGS FGDC documents, extracting symbols. I am clipping the symbol from the PDF, then converting it to SVG in Inkscape. Currently, I have some bedding, joint and cleavage, and will keep building the list. Let me know if you would like the current SVGs (just 12) to check them out. They will go on my website some time this year (2017).

Answer (score 6):

You may find some symbols here:

http://geo.distortions.net/2010/12/geologic-symbology-for-qgis.html

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/1694

https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Geologic_Cross_Section

and a Howto:

http://gmcgeology.blogspot.de/2014/05/creating-geologic-maps-in-qgis-strike.html

I assume that the people behind those pages have the geological background to help you further.

Comment: Giuseppe Aruta has also a collection of geological symbols for OpenJUMP. I do not know if they can be used in QGIS but have a look. Zip contains a catalog in PDF format http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opensit/Openjump/Geological_Symbology.zip

Answer (score 4):

I have over 700 point symbols created and tested for use on my geological maps, using the USGS symbol documents as a source (https://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/), converting the original PDF using Inkscape. They are at http://members.iinet.net.au/~richard.langford/USGS.zip.

Answer (score 1):

> Alshaghdari, Mohsen. (2017). lithology symbols for geological mapping. . 10.13140/RG.2.2.19590.47687.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319964423_lithology_symbols_for_geological_mapping

Provides for lithology symbols for QGIS and other app mapping.

Comment: Technically this is a link only answer, which is frowned upon, but then the question in its nature almost requires links.  and indeed the other up-voted answer is also link only...  You should edit the answer so for example reference the work itself.  I have had a go, but please feel free to change if desired