# Changing SVG marker color using Expression String Builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, svg

What is the proper way to use the Expression String Builder to set a specific color for an SVG symbol?

I found some geology svg symbols through this StackExchange answer that I had been looking for https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/269648/65188. The documentation for the USGS symbol library states, "In addition, modifying the size, color, and (or) lineweight of an existing symbol to suit the needs of a particular map or output device also is permitted", however, I am not able to change the color of my svg symbol. The Fill Color and the Stroke Color options in the Layer Styling panel are not automatically available, so I believe using the Expression String Builder is the way to go. Below are some of the unsuccessful expressions that I tried.

1. color_rgb( 179,14,238)
2. @symbol_color =color_rgb( 179,14,238)
3. '#b709f6'
4. '[179,14,238,0]'

Using QGIS v. 3.14 on Windows 10

Comment: Are you sure that you can change the color of these specific svg ? If yes you should be able to manualy select the color, if not look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45180/how-to-create-svg-symbols-that-have-modifiable-fill-color-stroke-color-and-stro?r=SearchResults to learn how to make your svg editable

Comment: It seems possible with the svg's that come with QGIS, but not others for some reason...

Comment: Thanks, J.R, that link was helpful. I followed those instructions and was able to edit the color, but the symbol became all wonky. It might be because I was unable to set stroke-linecap, stroke-linejoin, and stroke-miterlimit parameters. I wasn't sure what the default calls for those were. I ended up finding the ESRI Geology symbols as part of the Font marker collection in QGIS and all the sybology settings were modifiable, so I just went with that.